# For what value(s) of $a$ does this $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^{\sin x}-a^{\tan x}}{\tan x -\sin x}$ equal $1?$

Tags: calculus, limits

> For what value(s) of $a$ does this $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^{\sin x}-a^{\tan x}}{\tan x -\sin x}$$ equal $1?$

Is there any simple way to do this? I have used L' Hospital's rule repeatedly and ended up with more and more complicated expressions and got the wrong answer

Comment: Have you tried to use Taylor's series?

Comment: @Arararararagi-kun No Will try it now

Comment: My solution involves taylor expanding $a^{\sin x}, a^{\tan x}$ as $e^{\sin x \ln a} = \sum (\frac{\sin(x) \ln a)^k}{k!}$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

$a>0$; Set $a=e^y$;

MVT:

$-y\frac{e^{y\tan x}-e^{y\sin x}}{y\tan x -y\sin x}= -y(e^z)$,

where

$z \in (\min (y\sin x, y\tan x), \max (y\sin x,y \tan x))$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (-ye^z)=-ye^0=1$;

$y=-1$; and $a=e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use Taylor series.  You may know

- $\tan(x)=x +\frac13 x^3+\cdots$
- $\sin(x)=x -\frac16 x^3+\cdots$

This suggests that in the denominator you will get $\frac12 x^3+\cdots$ and may need to consider $x^3$ in the numerator.  Meanwhile

- $\exp(x)=1 + x +\frac12 x^2 + \frac16 x^3+\cdots$
- $a^x = \exp(\log_e(a)x) = 1 + \log_e(a)x +\frac12 \log_e(a)^2 x^2 + \frac16 x^3\log_e(a)^3+\cdots$

which leads to

- $a^{\sin(x)} = 1 + \log_e(a)x +\frac12 \log_e(a)^2 x^2 +  (\frac16\log_e(a)^3-\frac16\log_e(a))x^3+\cdots$
- $a^{\tan(x)} = 1 + \log_e(a)x +\frac12 \log_e(a)^2 x^2 +  (\frac16\log_e(a)^3+\frac13\log_e(a))x^3+\cdots$

and that gives $$\dfrac{a^{\sin(x)}-a^{\tan(x)}}{\tan(x)-\sin(x)} = \dfrac{-\frac12\log_e(a)x^3+\cdots}{\frac12x^3+\cdots} \to -\log_e(a)$$

Finally:  $-\log_e(a) = 1 \implies \log_e(a) = -1 \implies a=e^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{e}$

Comment: Why the $\log_e$ ? Just use plain $\ln$.

Comment: @zwim - because some mathematicians ask why I do not just use $\log()$ and I see $\log_e()$ as an unambiguous compromise

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the limit,

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^{\sin x} - a^{\tan x}}{\tan x - \sin x} 
=-\ln a\cdot\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin x\ln a} - e^{\tan x\ln a}}{\sin x\ln a - \tan x\ln a}  
$$

$$=-\ln a\cdot \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\sin x\ln a - \tan x\ln a+O(x^2)}{\sin x\ln a - \tan x\ln a} = -\ln a = 1$$

Thus, $a=\frac1e$

Comment: Hmm, I have an issue with that. $\sin x\ln a-\tan x\ln a=O(x^3)$ thus your ratio is worth $1+ \frac{O(x^2)}{O(x^3)}\to\infty$, you need to go further in developping the numerator!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly we must have $a>0$ for the numerator to make sense and further if $a=1$ the limit is $0$. Thus we must have $a>0,a\neq 1$. Rewriting the expression under limit as $$-a^{\sin x} \cdot\frac{a^{\tan x-\sin x} - 1}{\tan x - \sin x} $$ we can see that it tends to $-1\cdot \log a=\log(1/a)$. Now it should be obvious that the desired value of $a$ is $1/e$.